# python error "can't assign to function call"

Tags: python, syntax

this is my code:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self,root):
        frame=tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack()
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(frame,text='打招呼',fg = command = self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack()

    def say_hi(self):
        print('互联网的广大朋友们大家好，我是小甲鱼')

root=tk.Tk()
app=App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

`fg = command = self.say_hi` is invalid syntax; Change to `command = self.say_hi` then it runs

Comment: @user7727210 you should accept the answer by ticking it off